# Create pkg from Xcode Swift MacOS project

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm very new with Xcode...

I created my first Swift macOS (no iOS) application with Xcode: is there an easy way to test it on another mac (for example by creating a pkg)?

I would not like to spend time to create the application and then fail to create the installer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **PackageMaker** application. **PackageMaker** can be found as part of `Auxiliary Tools for Xcode` which downloaded from [here](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/auxiliary_tools_for_xcode__late_july_2012/xcode44auxtools6938114a.dmg)

---

[image]

Comment: Ok, if I successfully close the application I will create an apple development account for PackageMaker... :-)